# Can the current search_path be used in a query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema IN (search_path)
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-settings.html) is a system view containing all the configuration options and their values available in the current context:

> The view pg_settings provides access to run-time parameters of the server. It is essentially an alternative interface to the SHOW and SET commands. It also provides access to some facts about each parameter that are not directly available from SHOW, such as minimum and maximum values.

This view you can query just like any other, so you can get the value of `search_path` like this:

```
SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path';
```

The returned value is a `text`, with the delimiter being `', '`.  Some tinkering is needed so that you can compare `table_schema` to this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema = ANY (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(setting, ', ')) 
                             FROM pg_settings
                            WHERE name = 'search_path');
```

This is still only half perfect, as `"$user"` can be in the `search_path`.  One way to solve this is to replace it with the current user like

```
... replace(setting, '"$user"', CURRENT_USER) ...
```

See all this at work on [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5d76d477b110433dcaf335fa34f2ceac).

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! One small correction for me though: The delimiter seems to only be `,`, without the space.

Comment: @xehpuk that's surprising, at me it works both ways.

Comment: I'm on version 9.6.8, if that makes any difference. Couldn't find any changes in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the `search_path` of the current session, then you can use the `current_setting()` function for that:

```
SELECT current_setting('search_path')
```

```
 current_setting
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

If you also want the *effective search path* for the current session, `current_schemas(include_implicit boolean)` is your friend; it returns a `NAME[]` array with the schemas from the `search_path` which exist and which the user has `GRANT USAGE` permissions on:

```
SELECT current_setting('search_path'), current_schemas(false);
```

```
 current_setting | current_schemas
-----------------+-----------------
 "$user", public | {public}
(1 row)
```

If, for the `include_implicit` parameter, you supply `true` instead of `false`, `current_schemas()` will also show you the schemas which are implicitly added to the effective search path:

```
SELECT current_setting('search_path'), current_schemas(true);
```

```
 current_setting |        current_schemas
-----------------+-------------------------------
 "$user", public | {pg_catalog,public}
(1 row)
```

Including the `pg_tmp_<nnn>` schema if the current session has any temporary objects:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a (b INT);
SELECT current_schemas(true);
```

```
CREATE TABLE
        current_schemas
-------------------------------
 {pg_temp_3,pg_catalog,public}
(1 row)
```

Also, the `"$user"` expansion will be done for you, if the `"$user"` schema exists:

```
CREATE ROLE xehpuk;
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION xehpuk;
SELECT current_setting('search_path'), current_schemas(false);
```

```
 current_setting | current_schemas
-----------------+-----------------
 "$user", public | {xehpuk,public}
(1 row)
```

If you want to dive deeper into `search_path`s, I just published an [extremely long “summary”](https://blog.bigsmoke.us/2022/11/11/postgresql-schema-search_path) of its power and its pitfalls.